# Scala: is it possible to restrict access to the function definitions of a trait to its direct callers?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, traits

I have a Trait `LoggerHelper`. Inside I have some function definitions. I want them to be accessible by the classes extending this trait but I would like to restrict the access for the classes injecting the classes extending this trait.

Example:

```
Trait LoggerHelper {
  def log() = ???
} 

Class A extends LoggerHelper {
  log() //OK
}

Class B @Inject() (a: A) {
  a.log() //I want this line does not compile
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `protected` member can be accessed only from subclasses of the class where the member is defined:

```scala
scala> trait LoggerHelper {
     |   protected def log() = ???
     | }
defined trait LoggerHelper

scala> class A extends LoggerHelper {
     |   log()
     | }
defined class A

scala> class B(a: A) {
     |   a.log()
     | }
<console>:13: error: method log in trait LoggerHelper cannot be accessed in A
 Access to protected method log not permitted because
 enclosing class B is not a subclass of
 trait LoggerHelper where target is defined
         a.log()
           ^
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this but since Intellij still proposes the methods in auto-completion, I thought that it did not work. Maybe do you know any way to make IntelliJ not proposing them?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be worthwhile to check if you are using Intellij IDEA _Ultimate_ Edition and have the Guice plugin enabled: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184191 Or you could consider reporting the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I have the Ultimate edition with the guice plugin enabled, so indeed I'm gonna open an issue. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

A member protected using `protected[this]` may only be accessed from `this` instance of the class, and its subclasses.

```
class Base{
    protected val alpha ="Alpha";
    protected[this] def sayHello = "Hello";
    def foo = Console println(new Base().sayHello) // won't compile
    def bar = Console println(this.sayHello)
}
class Derived extends Base{
    def hello = println(this.sayHello) ;
    //def hello2 = println((new Derived() .sayHello) // won't compile
}
```

A member protected using `protected` may be accessed from any instance of the class where the member is defined, and from their subclasses.

```
class Base{
    protected val alpha ="Alpha";
    protected def sayHello = "Hello";
}
class Derived extends Base{
    def hello = println(this.sayHello);
    def hello2 = println((new Derived()).sayHello); // has access to sayHello() in the original instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restrict protected method with [this], like

```
trait LoggerHelper {
  protected[this] def log() = ???
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of [this] here? Does it provide something more than the @dkim answer?